# Não estou conseguindo renderizar Imagem com Image - React-native

Tags: react-native, image, expo, uri

Senhores(as).
Quando escrevo dessa forma:

`<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}

</View>`

me retorna " Error while updating property 'src' of a view managed by:RCTImageView  null  Value for uri cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to string"

se escrevo dessa forma:

```
 <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />                   
   {image !== '' ? <View>
    <Image source={{uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
    </View>:null}
```

esta me retornado: 'Warning: Failed prop type:Invalid prop 'source' supplied to 'Image'

posso estar errado mas creio que ambos estejam relacionado ao source... mas não sei como corrigir.

a uri:image vem da função:

```
async function pickImage(){
    try {
        const result  =  await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1,
        })
        if (!result.cancelled){
            setimage({image:result.uri})
            console.log(result.uri)
        }
    } catch (E) {
        console.log(E)

    }
}
```

console.log(result.uri) esta retornando "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fapp-bc4b4820-9594-491f-bfdb-cd2750d6f674/ImagePicker/905aa553-a340-4516-a4b5-4310ed91289e.jpg"

desde já agradeço!!

Answer (score 0):

estava passando a Uri de forma errada, onde estava:

```
setimage({image:result.uri})
```

deveria ser assim:

```
setimage(result.uri)
```